# Heroku Initial Push Failure

Tags: python, heroku

I was following this quickstart guide: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python but when I got to the part where I was going to "git push heroku master" it gave me the following logs. :(  If anyone could help me it would be really appreciated.  I've removed and recreated the initial app about 4 times and it's always the same problem.

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1.12 KiB, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Python app detected
-----> Preparing virtualenv version 1.7
   New python executable in ./bin/python
   Installing     distribute.............................................................................................................................................................................................done.
   Installing pip...............done.
-----> Activating virtualenv
-----> Installing dependencies using pip version 1.0.2
   Downloading/unpacking Flask==0.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
   Creating supposed download cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads
     Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FF%2FFlask%2FFlask-0.8.tar.gz
     Running setup.py egg_info for package Flask

       warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
   Downloading/unpacking Jinja2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
     Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FJ%2FJinja2%2FJinja2-2.6.tar.gz
     Running setup.py egg_info for package Jinja2

       warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
   Downloading/unpacking PyRSS2Gen==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
     Downloading PyRSS2Gen-1.0.0.tar.gz
     Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FP%2FPyRSS2Gen%2FPyRSS2Gen-1.0.0.tar.gz
     Running setup.py egg_info for package PyRSS2Gen

   Downloading/unpacking Twisted==11.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
     Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FT%2FTwisted%2FTwisted-11.0.0.tar.bz2
     Running setup.py egg_info for package Twisted

   Downloading/unpacking Werkzeug==0.8.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
     Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2FW%2FWerkzeug%2FWerkzeug-0.8.3.tar.gz
     Running setup.py egg_info for package Werkzeug

       warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'werkzeug/debug/templates'
       warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
       warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
       no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
   Downloading/unpacking altgraph==0.7.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
     Downloading altgraph-0.7.1.tar.gz
     Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/http%3A%2F%2Fpypi.python.org%2Fpackages%2Fsource%2Fa%2Faltgraph%2Faltgraph-0.7.1.tar.gz
     Running setup.py egg_info for package altgraph
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
         File "/tmp/build_qhsjytq4dlst/build/altgraph/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
           LONG_DESCRIPTION += open('doc/changelog.rst', 'rU').read()
       IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'doc/changelog.rst'
       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
       Traceback (most recent call last):

     File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

     File "/tmp/build_qhsjytq4dlst/build/altgraph/setup.py", line 31, in <module>

       LONG_DESCRIPTION += open('doc/changelog.rst', 'rU').read()

   IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'doc/changelog.rst'

   ----------------------------------------
   Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
   Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:PRIVATENAME.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:PRIVATENAME.git'</code>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/altgraph/issue/2/071-cannot-be-installed-from-release there is a bug with release 0.7.1 of altgraph which causes this failure.

Judging from the log, you may be able to fix this by changing line 6 of your requirements.txt file to request a different version of altgraph.

There is a 0.7.2 you could try, or even more recent 0.8 and 0.9 versions.